# Why wasn't the Night King naked in S08E03?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

So we know that the Unburnt (e.g. Daenerys Targaryen) are fireproof, and presumably the Night King is one of the Unburnt.

However, the Night King's clothing is unharmed after an extended blast of dragon's fire (*Game of Thrones* S08E03), unlike Daenerys' previous encounters with fire. Why is this?

Comment: Is "Unburnt" a group or quality openly described in GoT, or was it just a title taken up by Daenerys after she spent a night in a bonfire and emerged... unburned? I've always thought the second. Are there any connections implied between Daenerys' and the Night King's powers, beyond that one effect?

Comment: In researching this further it sounds like Daenerys just took that title, and there is no “class” of unburnt people. Plot holes and fan service aside, that would explain why the two powers might have different sources/effects.

Comment: The "unburnt" isn't a category or group. It's just Daenerys, so I'm not sure what you can extrapolate from that.

Comment: @Upper_Case that's correct.  "Unburnt" is a title that Daenerys has claimed, not any sort of category of people.

Comment: Plot twist: he is naked, that's his skin.

Comment: Because only female characters parade around naked.  "You must be new hereXXXX to HBO"  :-)

Comment: It's a misconception that Dany is fireproof. The dragon birth was a ONE TIME event of fireproofness. Interview with GRRM:
"Thanks for asking that. It gives me a chance to clear up a common misconception. TARGARYENS ARE NOT IMMUNE TO FIRE! The birth of Dany’s dragons was unique, magical, wonderous, a miracle. She is called The Unburnt because she walked into the flames and lived." Question: "So she won’t be able to do it again?" and Martin replied, "Probably not." https://web.archive.org/web/20000615222300/http://www.eventhorizon.com/sfzine/chats/transcripts/031899.html

Comment: D&D didn't imagine a scenario where GoT fans want to see Night King naked.

Comment: @Chro This question is not about the books. Dany is absolutely 100% fireproof *in the show*, as we have seen numerous times. Completely different canons.

Comment: @only_pro, my wife has been re-watching the show and noticed that Dany does burn, but she heals very quickly from the burn. I suspect that if exposed to enough heat (e.g. thrown down a volcano), she probably would die.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Possible in-universe answer:

- Whatever charm he used to shield himself from fire surrounds him, leaving his clothing and weapon unharmed.

Narrative answer:

Nudity is often used to connote vulnerability.  Having the Night King appear sky-clad after a display of power meant to sink everyone's hearts would have produced a contrary effect.  *(Plus, I doubt anyone wants to see a White Walker's willie!;)*

Comment: Interesting point about the narrative, although when we first learned that Daenerys was fireproof, her nudity symbolized her *in*-vulnerability.

Comment: @catichenor great point about inverting conventions.  In that scene, she has just given birth, so the nudity makes sense.

Comment: Those guys were dressed so well and were so cool I actually wanted them to win! Clothes maketh the dude.

Comment: @void_ptr Given that this is Game of Thrones we’re talking about here, your tl;dr is drastically inaccurate. Neither boobs nor lack thereof have ever been a reason to avoid nudity in the series.

Comment: While nudity often connotes vulnerability, it can also do the opposite, and show sheer brute strength. Have you forgotten (the cinematic marvel, *cough*) *Scorpion King*? Quick recap: The Rock was fully clothed for most of the movie, much to the surprise of the viewers. Until the finale, in which he finally shed the shackles of civilisation and ascended to a new level of power (or some such nonsense). Anyway, the situation is clearly different here but I’m sure they could have made it work, cinematographically. I find an in-Universe answer more compelling.

Comment: Maybe add that WW’s clothes also get destroyed by stabs with valerian steel

Comment: The second part of this answer is just "It's just written that way" said differently. :/

Comment: @CarlWitthoft So? That doesn’t seem related to what I wrote.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's hard for me to remember the plot of films like Scorpion King (they are so forgettable) but wasn't that scene indicating rebirth, as with Dany after her trial by fire?

Comment: @TheAnathema Not exactly. It provides a reason *why* it was written that way (if you agree with that or not), which goes a lot further with regards to an actual explanation and answer to the question.

Answer (score 103):

Daenerys appears to be protected though an immunity (or at least, a high resistance) to fire, whereas the Night King appears to be protected through the sheer cold that radiates from him.

While it isn't depicted consistently, fire in the vicinity of the Night King does tend to snuff out, as seen in S06E05 "The Door" when the Children of the Forest create a firewall to defend the Three-Eyed Raven and Bran from the Night King, who simply walks through the fire and snuffs it out.

Put in a more 'computer gamey' way, Daenerys's fire resistance ends at her skin, whereas the White Walker's cold is more like an aura effect.

Comment: He also summoned/projected the cold with the cold front that enveloped the dragons, snuffed out the residual effects of their fire, and prevented the defenders of Winterfell from igniting the trenches by more conventional means.  Good analogies in the answer.

Comment: This answer makes more sense than the one marked correct.

Comment: Very good answer, based on facts and observations within the show.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I agree that it's an excellent in-universe answer!  (Where I just indicate that the Night King's magic may be an area of effect, Ingolifs presents a prior referent.)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's not really that it makes more or less sense. This is an attempt at an in-universe answer while the other is more of an out-of-universe answer.

Comment: Can i just add the Daenerys is not fire proof. GRMM and the producers have stated this multiple times. It was 1 time thing that happened.

Comment: @GamerGypps In the show it was 2 times, not just one. It happened again when she burned the Khals in Vaes Dothrak.

Comment: A good theory with a slight problem: something that cold would freeze anything/anyone who came near it. Arya would have frozen before she could stab him, unless his resistance is something he turns on and off.

Comment: The cold effect does seem to be portrayed inconsistently in the shows. In the books, the characters feel bitter cold when approached by a white walker, whereas no one really seems to feel cold in the show.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is that he was. Those aren't clothes, they're just an integral part of his being. Otherwise, they wouldn't have shattered into a million ice crystals when he did.

Grantedly, I have no source to support this theory, but it does feel internally consistent.